# How to obtain the Lyapunov candidate of this system

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I have been trying to find a suitable Lyapunov function for this system

$\dot{x_{1}} = \sin(x_{2})$

$\dot{x_{2}} = -x_{1}-x_{2}$

As can be noted it has multiple equilibrium points:

Equilibrium Points: $(-n\pi,n\pi)$ where $n = ... -2,-1, 0,+1,+2 ...$

When n is even the equilibrium point is stable focus, but when odd the equilibrium point is a saddle.
I tried this:

$V = x^{T}Px + (1-\cos(x_{2}))$

For V to be positive definite we need $P_{11}+P_{12} >0$ and $P_{11}P_{22}-(P_{12})^{2}>0$, where $P$ is a $2\times 2$ symmetric matrix ($P_{12} = P_{21}$). The time derivative of Lyapunov candidate is:

$$ \dot{V} = \dot{x_{1}}x_{1}P_{11} + \dot{x_{2}}x_{1}P_{12} + \dot{x_{1}}x_{2}P_{12} + \dot{x_{2}}x_{2}P_{22} + \dot{x_{2}} \sin(x_{2})  $$

By solving I get to the point:

$ \dot{V} = (-P_{12} - P_{22})x_{1}x_{2} - P_{12}x_{1}^{2} - P_{22}x_{2}^{2} + (P_{12} -1)x_{2}sin(x_{2}) +(P_{11} -1)x_{1}\sin(x_{2}) $

In this point I tried to make:
$$-P_{12}-P_{22} = 0\longrightarrow P_{12} = -P_{22}\tag1$$
$$P_{11} -1 =0 \tag2$$

And we also assume that:

$$P_{12}>0\tag3$$

$$P_{22}>0 \tag4$$

$$P_{12}-1 <0\longrightarrow P_{12}<1\tag5$$

So we can guarantee that $\dot{V}$ is negative definite in the domain $-\pi<x_{2}<\pi$. But the problem manifests here. If we are suppose to satisfy $(5)$ and $(3)$ we obtain that:

$$0<P_{12}<1$$

If I assign $P_{12} = 0.5$ from $(1)$ we can say that $P_{22} = -0.5$ but this value does satisfy $(4)$ and this is my MAIN issue with this. I don't know I my math went wrong, or if I just went trough the wrong process, the process I used for this exercise was similar to the process one can follow to obtain a Lyapunov function that guarantee asymptotic stability for a pendulum with friction problem, but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your first constraint from $(1)$, that $P_{12} = -P_{22}$, it not necessary. If we still set $P_{11}=1$ and $P_{12}=1/2$ yields

$$
\dot{V} = -\frac{1}{2} x^\top
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{2}+P_{22} \\
\frac{1}{2}+P_{22} & 2\,P_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
}_Q x - \frac{1}{2}x_2\,\sin(x_2). \tag{1}
$$

The matrix $Q$ can only be made positive semi-definite when $P_{22} = 1/2$, which simplifies $(1)$ to

$$
\dot{V} = -\frac{1}{2} (x_1 + x_2)^2 - \frac{1}{2}x_2\,\sin(x_2), \tag{2}
$$

which is negative definite for $-\pi < x_2 < \pi$.

---

Another option is to make all non-polynomial terms of the time derivative of the Lyapunov function zero, which can be done using $P_{11}=P_{12}=1$. This only enables you to get a negative semi-definite result at best when using $P_{22}=1$, yielding

$$
\dot{V} = -(x_1 + x_2)^2. \tag{3}
$$

Using [LaSalle's invariance principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaSalle%27s_invariance_principle) you can still show that all initial conditions converge to one of the equilibria (though, this does not show that most initial conditions converge to the stable equilibria with even $n$).